# Whose Grifter goes first?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

In *Doomtown Reloaded*, [Grifters](http://www.alderac.com/doomtown/2014/04/14/grifting-consistency/) are characters who allow you to look at your starting hand and, if you don't like them, boot them. For instance, [Travis Moone](http://dtdb.co/en/card/01049) allow you to boot him and then redraw your hand.

Recently I played a game where both of us had Grifters and it was important to know whose Grifter went first. Basically, my opponent was on the fence about using his Grifter and wanted to know if my Grifter was going to start the first round booted.

Since Grifters activate after the initial hand draw but before the first lowball round, we didn't have an established way to decide whose Grifter went first. So whose Grifter goes first? Or do you just count to three and decide simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [November 2014 tournament floor rules](http://www.alderac.com/doomtown/files/2014/11/Doomtown-Floor-Rules-Effective-23-nov.pdf) answers this:

> Before the first turn of the game if there are effects/reacts that
>   could be conflicting before a winner has been determined by lowball
>   (E.G. Grifter abilities), use the following procedure:
>
> 1. All players make a choice as to whether they are going to use or pass on the grifter ability. Each player then holds their hand out
>      with a concealed token in there, with an agreed colour code, red for
>      use and blue for no use.
> 2. If a player fails to hold out a token of either colour then they pass the use of the grifter.
> 3. Both players open their hands at the same time and use the ability or not as indicated.

In friendly games, we usually don't worry about this, and even in tournaments in my experience it is resolved without resorting to this 90% of the time.